# Webdings font characters not extracted using pdfbox

Tags: pdfbox

I am using pdfbox to get the names of all fonts that are used in a pdf.

So far it was working well. However, I recently came across a pdf that has 'Webdings' font. PDFBox was not able to identify it.Could anyone help please.

This is the code I have used:

```
public static Set<String> extractFonts(String pdfPath) throws IOException 
{
        PDDocument  doc = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfPath));

        PDPageTree pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
        Set<String> fontSet = new HashSet<String>();
        try{
            for(PDPage page:pages){
                    PDResources res = page.getResources();
                    for (COSName fontName : res.getFontNames())
                    {
                        PDFont font = res.getFont(fontName);
                        if(font != null){
                            String fontUsedName = font.getName();
                            if(fontUsedName.contains("+")) {
                                fontUsedName = fontUsedName.substring(fontUsedName.indexOf("+")+1, fontUsedName.length());
                            }
                            fontSet.add(fontUsedName);
                        }
                    }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(fontSet);
        return fontSet;
    }
```

I was able to know that the font 'Webdings' is present from the File-> Properties->Fonts option in Adobe Reader

Comment: *"Could anyone help please."* - Hardly without the sample PDF.

Comment: Please do also edit to include the code you used and the version. And clarify how you know it has the Webdings font, and how it wasn't identified, i.e. where it was missing.

Comment: Are you sure the font is in the page resources and not in the resources of some embedded form xobject? Or probably some pattern?

Comment: I just got to know that the font was used in art, most likely placed as an eps file. Any ideas as to how I can extract that?